# Php array insert not last but first

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to sort by publishedAt. The sql is inserting from json data and I need to get the newest, but this code getting the oldest.

What is wrong with my code?

```
$loop = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT channelid, videoId FROM users ORDER BY id")
    or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
    {
        $channelid = $row['channelid'];
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelid .'&maxResults=5&key=KEY';
        $content = file_get_contents($url); 
        $json = json_decode($content, true);    

        if(!isset($json['items'])) continue; //skip if no items

        $videos = ['videoId'=>'','videoId1'=>'','videoId2'=>'','videoId3'=>'','videoId4'=>''];
        $i = 0;

        foreach($json['items'] as $items)
        {
            $publishedAt = $items['snippet']['publishedAt'];
            $key  = 0==$i ? 'videoId' : 'videoId'.$i;
            $videos[$key] = $items['id']['videoId']; 
            ++$i;
        }
        $ii = 0;


        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(channelid, publishedAt, videoId, videoId1, videoId2, videoId3, videoId4) VALUES('$channelid', '$publishedAt', '{$videos['videoId']}', '{$videos['videoId1']}', '{$videos['videoId2']}', '{$videos['videoId3']}', '{$videos['videoId4']}')    
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelid=VALUES(channelid), publishedAt=VALUES(publishedAt), videoId=VALUES(videoId), videoId1=VALUES(videoId1), videoId2=VALUES(videoId2), videoId3=VALUES(videoId3), videoId4=VALUES(videoId4);
            ";
        mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
        if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're looping over `$json['items']` and overwriting `$publishedAt` on every iteration, so at the end it keeps the value of the last item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're looping through `$json['items']` you're overwriting `$publishedAt` with the last item for each loop.

If you only want the publishedAt of your first item you should get the first item directly (no loop necessary).
But if you want to insert every items you should put your query inside the foreach.